# Render tabsetPanel under tabPanel in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

I want to have multiple tabs under tabPanel-3. I tried inserting another tabsetPanel under tabPanel, but it didn't work.

```
  output$mytabs = renderUI({

  tabs = 
         tabsetPanel(
 tabPanel('Tab1', wellPanel(checkboxInput('All','Check  All/Uncheck All',T),uiOutput('tab1'))),

 tabPanel('Tab2', gridster(tile.width = 100, tile.height = 100,
 gridsterItem(row = 1, col = 1, size.x = 1, size.y = 1,style='background-color:#FFFFFF',
              tags$div(class = 'grid_title', 'Tab2 - Title'), htmlOutput("tab2")))),


  tabPanel('Tab3',
  gridster(tile.width = 250, tile.height = 1000,
  gridsterItem(row = 1, col = 1, size.x = 1, size.y = 1,style='background-color:#FFFFFF',
            tags$div(class = 'grid_title', 'Tab 3- Plot 1'), showOutput("Chart1","nvd3")),

  gridsterItem(row = 2, col = 1, size.x = 1, size.y = 1,style='background-color:#FFFFFF',
            tags$div(class = 'grid_title', 'Tab 3 - Plot 2'), chartOutput("Chart2"))

         ))

   )


   mainPanel(tabs)

  })

  outputOptions(output, "mytabs", suspendWhenHidden = T)
```

Comment: Run a search request on [the shiny google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss) using *nested* as the keyword, you will find several discussions about this.

Comment: Thanks Stephane Laurent!